# Sed pattern multiple maching

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I need do a job like:

```
echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed 's/(\.tif)|(\.jpg)//g'
```

expect result:

```
apa bib
```

but I got the result:

```
apa.tif bib.jpg
```

please someone help me out of this. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your sed command like below,

```
$ echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed 's/\.tif\|\.jpg//g'
apa bib
```

OR

```
$ echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed 's/\.\(tif\|jpg\)//g'
apa bib
```

In basic sed, you need to escape `|` symbol to make it do a regex OR operation. And also you need to escape `(`, `)` symbols in-order to do capturing.

Your regex would be modified as,

```
$ echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed 's/\(\.tif\)\|\(\.jpg\)//g'
apa bib
```

Comment: +1, why should anyone on earth downvote this? this works alryt, else the question is not clarifying the requirement well. Perhaps it was accidental :-)

Comment: you are right! I got that. thanks. but I miss something, I using the shell of Max OS, and the sed is not GNU sed, but BSD sed. it's so different with that. so, when I try: `echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed 's/\.tif\|\.jpg//g' `, it steal not working. finally, I got the solution: `echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed -E 's/(\.tif)|(\.jpg)//g' ` , this is work on Mac OS. thanks again man!

Comment: You don't need to use capturing groups, just `echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed -E 's/\.tif|\.jpg//g'` would be fine, or `echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed -E 's/\.(tif|jpg)//g'`

Comment: sure. I changed my code to : `echo "apa.tif bib.jpg"|sed -E 's/\.(tif|jpg)//g'`. and I try your command above in CentOS, it works great!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "apa.tif bib.jpg" | sed -r 's/\.[^ \s\t]+//g'
```

Comment: Could also use `sed -r 's/\.\w+//g'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try executing multiple commands like this:

```
sed -e 's/\.tif//g' -e 's/\.jpg//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "apa.tif bib.jpg bad.tiffany.png" | sed 's/\.\(tif|jpg\)\( |$\)/\1/g'
```

in case of, to exclude non extension pattern match

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk` for this:

```
echo "apa.tif bib.jpg" | awk '{gsub(/\.tif|\.jpg/,"")}1'
apa bib
```